# update one field of a table from another controller while save the data

Tags: cakephp

I have a manage_returns_controller and it has two action,add and index.It has one product dropdown,one stock dropdown and add button.And I also have manage_products_controller that contains a field stock.But now I want to do the following

When I click on the returns controller's add button then simultaneously save the return data as well as increase the stock in the product table.

heres the add action code

```
function add($id = null) 
    {
       /*$this->pageTitle   =   "Edit Exchange";*/

        $storeval = $this->Store->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('is_deleted'=>0,'is_blocked'=>0)));
        //$storeval=$this->Store->findByName();
        $storevalas = array();
        foreach($storeval as $storevall)
        {
            $storevalas[$storevall['Store']['id']] = $storevall['Store']['name'];
        }

        $this->set('stock_entry_option_store', $storevalas);


        //$product_name = $this->Exchange->product->find('list');
        $storevaldd = $this->Product->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('is_deleted'=>0,'is_blocked'=>0)));
        //$storeval=$this->Store->findByName();
        $product_name = array();
        foreach($storevaldd as $storevall)
        {
            $product_name[$storevall['Product']['id']] = $storevall['Product']['name'];
        }

        $this->set('stock_entry_option_product',$product_name);

        $this->Return->id = $id;
        if(!empty($id)){
            $button_name = "Update";
            $msg_act =   "updated";
$this->pageTitle    =   "Edit Return";
        } else {
            $button_name = "Add";
            $msg_act =   "added";
$this->pageTitle    =   "Add Return";
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) 
        {
            $this->data = $this->Return->read();
        }
        else 
        {
            if ($this->Return->save($this->data)) 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Return successfully '.$msg_act.'.',true),'default',array('class' => 'success')); 
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'ManageReturns','action' => 'index'));
            }
        }

        $this->set('button_name',$button_name);


    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: but how am i increase in stock field when I insert in return table?

Comment: stock field is column of which table???

Comment: product table.and I wanna update this when i insert the data in return field?u got it?plz give me a solution

Comment: Write a function in the Product model that increases the stock field. Then call that function from within this controller.